# How to follow a publisher/subscriber strategy in C# or .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the most suitable language construct in C# or class or function in .NET's BCL to follow a [publisher/subscriber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) (aka. [signals/slots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots)) strategy?

Answer (score 7):

Events in C# and VB are the typical language construct for handling pub/sub:

```
public class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    private void RaiseEvent()
    {
        EventHandler handler = MyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public void Subscribe(Publisher pub)
    {
        pub.MyEvent += MethodToCall;
    }

    private void MethodToCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will be called from Publisher.RaiseEvent
    }
}
```

Alternatives include [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) and [WPF Commanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx).

Note that if the `Publisher` is long-lived but the `Subscriber` should be short-lived, the `Subscriber` will need to unsubscribe from the event - otherwise the `Publisher` will maintain a reference to the `Subscriber` due to the event, preventing garbage collection.

Comment: I would also implement IDisposable on the subscriber to ensure that the -= call is made on MyEvent. Otherwise the Publisher will leak.

Comment: @Marco: This was only meant to be a demonstration of the syntax really, not a best practices guide. There's a whole heap of things to know about events in reality. Also, in my experience you rarely *actually* need to unsubscribe - it's only if the publisher would otherwise outlive the subscriber, and while that can happen, it's relatively rare in my experience. I'll edit to mention this though.

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft article may also be useful in that it describes how the Observer design pattern can be implemented using .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648108.aspx